# Extract year, month and day numbers (1 to 2 digits) from a string (LibreOffice Base)

Tags: string, extract, hsqldb, libreoffice, radix

I am using LibreOffice Base (version 7.3) to create a database.
I need to extract year, month and day numbers from such strings that consist Chinese charactors as shown following. I think one Chinese charactor is one charactor but I am not sure.

What I have:
1997年8月12日
1971年10月1日
2001年5月26日
2005年12月29日
2010年2月8日
...

What I want to achieve:

1. I need to extract the first 4 digits which are the years;
2. The numbers between the first charactor (年) and the second charactor(月), which are months from 1 to 12 (1 or 2 digits);
3. The numbers between the second charactor (月) and the third charactor (日)，which are days in a month from 1 to 31 (1 or 2 digits);

I am a newbie, I tried using combination RIGHT() and LEFT() function or substring() method but I failed because of the fact the numbers of months and days are sometimes 1 digit sometimes 2 digits. I will be very grateful if someone can help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you didn't specify which built-in database you are using, Firebird or HSQLDB.

[image: Database type]

You didn't provide your table name and Chinese date field name. Therefore, I will show how this problem is solved for the Firebird database, a table named ChinaTest and a field named ChinaDate.

First, replace the first two characters with a dash, and the last character with an empty string (just delete it). This will be done by the [**REPLACE() function**](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-replace.html). Just nest three REPLACE()'s one inside the other:

`REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( "ChinaTest"."ChinaDate", '年', '-' ), '月', '-' ), '日', '' )`

Now the [**CAST() function**](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-cast.html) easily converts this string into a "real date":

`SELECT CAST( <previous_expression> AS DATE ) "RealDate" FROM "ChinaTest"`

When you have a real date, you can use the [**EXTRACT() function**](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-extract.html) to get any part of it.

The final solution might look like this:

```
SELECT "RealDate", EXTRACT( YEAR FROM "RealDate" ) "iYear", 
                   EXTRACT( MONTH FROM "RealDate" ) "iMonth", 
                   EXTRACT( DAY FROM "RealDate" ) "iDay" 
    FROM (SELECT CAST( 
                   REPLACE( 
                      REPLACE( 
                         REPLACE( "ChinaTest"."ChinaDate", '年', '-' ), 
                      '月', '-' ), 
                   '日', '' ) 
                  AS DATE ) "RealDate" FROM "ChinaTest")
```

[image: Result]

For a HSQLDB database, the query might look like this:

```
SELECT
 CAST( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( "Employess"."CNBirthDate", '年', '-' ), '月', '-' ), '日', '' ) AS DATE ) AS "BDate",
 YEAR( CAST( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( "Employess"."CNBirthDate", '年', '-' ), '月', '-' ), '日', '' ) AS DATE ) ) AS "BDYear",
 MONTH( CAST( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( "Employess"."CNBirthDate", '年', '-' ), '月', '-' ), '日', '' ) AS DATE ) ) AS "BDMonth",
 DAY( CAST( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( "Employess"."CNBirthDate", '年', '-' ), '月', '-' ), '日', '' ) AS DATE ) ) AS "BDDay" 
FROM "Employess"
```

[image: HSQLDB]

Comment: Hi John! Wow, that is absolutely beautiful! Very clear and logical. Thank you so much for the solution! Sorry I didn't know that LO BASE has  two built-in databases. I thought there was only one, which is HSQLDB. I am using HSQLDB. I will try to make it work in the HSQLDB. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi! Your codes work fine in SQL View:
[1]
Would like to make it work in Design View. I came across some problems:
[2]
I could get the date form after replacing the Chinese charactors like: 1959-6-28, but the RealDates I got through CAST() function are incomprehensible 5-digits numbers (like 21729, etc.). I could extract year, month and day with YEAR (), MONTH () and DAY () function, but the months "1-9" and the days "1-9" lack a "0"  before the numbers.
Sorry don't know how to upload database file.Thanks
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctLfD.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J502u.png

Comment: I used the following SQL syntax in the Query:

REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( [Employess].[CNBirthDate], '年', '-' ), '月', '-' ), '日', '' )

CAST( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( "Employess"."CNBirthDate", '年', '-' ), '月', '-' ), '日', '' ) AS DATE )

YEAR( CAST( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( [Employess].[CNBirthDate], '年', '-' ), '月', '-' ), '日', '' ) AS DATE ) )

MONTH( CAST( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( [Employess].[CNBirthDate], '年', '-' ), '月', '-' ), '日', '' ) AS DATE ) )

DAY( CAST( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( [Employess].[CNBirthDate], '年', '-' ), '月', '-' ), '日', '' ) AS DATE ) )

Comment: The five digit number is the number of days since the beginning of the XX century, which is how LibreOffice handles dates. Just try right clicking on the column heading with those weird numbers, select "Column Format" and set "Format-Date". I completed my answer with a variant for HSQLDB with a CNBirthDate field from the Employess table

Comment: Wow didn't know those are number of days!!! Thank you so much, dear John, also for the complementary answer for the HSQLDB. That's awesome! Much much appreciated!